# Searching a draft scenario, the api returns an empty array, and did not tell me a error type: Voximplant Kit

Tags: voximplant

https://voximplant.com/kit/docs/references/kit/scenarios#searchscenarios

Are the scenarios that I get via searchScenarios method limited by some status, like "in use"? I search a draft scenario, the api returns an empty array, and did not tell me a error type.

Answer (score 0):

The searchScenarios method returns all scenarios by default. You may use additional parameters like 'with_campaigns' or 'with_phones' to see if the scenario is in use. You may see all the additional parameters in our documentation: https://voximplant.com/kit/docs/references/kit/scenarios#searchscenarios